# How to hide some menu and add some menu dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I want to add or remove some menu items from my site in wordpress.
For example depending on some property I want to add menu item or remove menu item dynamically.

```
if(isset($userName)) {
   //print a menu item with the text as "Hello ".$userName;
   //print a menu item logout
   //hide login menu item
}
else {
  //hide logout
  //show login menu item
}
```

I wonder how it can be done, as menu in wordpress is static? Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Menu Item Visibility Control](http://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-items-visibility-control/) plugin. It shows the menu item only when a custom condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

you may use [if-menu plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/), i think it meets your need

Hope this answer may help you

Comment: but it provides specific options, i want a custom one that allow to specify option by my code